# Install Tensorflow in anaconda environment under Windows 10. cannot import html5lib

Tags: tensorflow

(tensorflow) C:\Users\HAHA\Documents>pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HAHA\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 6, in 
    from pip import main
  File "C:\Users\HAHA\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip__init__.py", line 28, in 
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\HAHA\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\vcs\subversion.py", line 9, in 
    from pip.index import Link
  File "C:\Users\HAHA\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 33, in 
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests, six
ImportError: cannot import name 'html5lib'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I downgraded the pip from 9.0.1 to 9.0.0 ( using anaconda navigator) and it worked.